# Parse message body using PHP Explode

Tags: php

I have the following message that I am trying to parse out of the body of the email. I am able to successfully get the email body but am running into problems pulling specific values from it. Here is an example of what the message body looks like:

John Doe just requested an service. Please see below for details: Name:John Doe
Number: 8884442222
Email: john@doe.com

I would like to be able to echo each of the following:
John Doe
8884442222
John@doe.com
123 Main St

Once I have them individually I would like to send a POST with the data. I can deal with the POST part.

Here is what im currently doing:

```
    $message = imap_fetchbody($connection,$email_number,1.1);
    if ($message == "") { // no attachments is the usual cause of this
        $message = imap_fetchbody($connection, $email_number, 1);
        $name = explode("Name:", $message);
        $wholename = $name[1];

        $nameExp = explode("/[\s]+/Number:", $wholename);
        $number = explode("Number:", $message);


        $nameFinal = $nameExp[0];
        $wholenumber = $number[1];

    }

//split the header array into variables
$status = ($header[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread');
$subject = $header[0]->subject;
$from = $header[0]->from;
$date = $header[0]->date;

echo "Whole name: " . $wholename . "<br>";
echo "Final name: " . $nameFinal . "<br>";
echo "whole number: " . $wholenumber . "<br>";
```

When I echo the full name I get all of the information after "Name:" (which is what is supposed to happen), same with number but when I just try to get the finalName it returns nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Explode is not a thing for text processing. Seeing that you already tried to use a regexp there, you should investigate this further ([`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match)). Also, since such mails commonly originate from some form, why wouldn't you be able to retrieve individual fieldst from some database?

Comment: PD of [Regex to match names and optional values](//stackoverflow.com/q/50110007) / [How to parse column separated key-value text with possible multiline strings](//stackoverflow.com/q/23012301) / etc.

Answer (score 4):

Just do it with plain regex, then you can access specific groups:

```
Name:(.+) Number: (\d+) Email:(.+) Address: (.+) Type of Property:
```

This will only work if the email is always in the same format - there's also missing group after 'Type of Property' but I don't know what would you write there - hopefully you get the idea.

Use https://regex101.com/ to help yourself out.

Comment: Probably needs `?` quantifiers, and the original mail somewhat likely contains newlines (even though OP hasn't shown actual source.)

Comment: @mario I don't know about the quantifiers, because after all, you set boundaries with `Name`, `Number` and so on.

But you are absolutely correct about the newlines - I've only had that much to work with, so I was hoping he could figure the rest on his own (such as the \s flag).

Comment: Or dividing into multiple regex specialised into finding particular sectors in the email (emails, numbers, etc). It can be a headache if dealing with worldwide information. But if local can be easier. In any case Regex is the way!

Comment: Thanks @JCode i have updated my question to reflect the new lines that are being created when i pull the message body